# Executing linux commands with c

Tags: c, linux, function, exec

Is there any way to execute Linux commands with c without using `execlp()`, like predefined functions or something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `system()` or `popen()` if you need the commands output.

Answer (score 2):

`system(const char *command);` sounds to be what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system`. It execute the command, but take care since it invoke a shell to interpret the command (breaking argument list on space, ...).